# Android - Disabling 3G and Enabling 2G

Tags: android, 3g

I found a lot of posts where people say you can't manage 3G/2G connection switch, but we all have widgets and such and I wanted to know if there is A way (even a console command) that would let my app automatically enable 2G connection, or a shortcut or just anything, because I'd need to disable 3G connection and let the user reactivate it. Is it possible in any way? I don't mind if a rooted phone is required :)

I know there isn't such an API, but there shall be a way in which widgets can work, and I'd love to know it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable 3G/2G in Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170472/how-to-enable-disable-3g-2g-in-android-sdk)

Comment: Not really, I'm not asking _only_ for SDK, but even for shell commands, just anything that can do :)