# How to enable/disable network setting "Use only 2G networks" via application widget(already present in the source code)?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to enable/disable network setting "Use only 2G networks" via application widget(already present in the source code). Is it possible? If yes, then please guide me.

Comment: Did you see this question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170472/how-to-enable-disable-3g-2g-in-android-sdk
There's something about that there

Comment: Hi Damian SIlvera, thanks for the quick reply. I have gone through the link that you have suggested. In my case, I am having the privilege of build i.e. I have created the application widget and build it into the source code, but question is how to enable/disable the "Use only 2G networks" settings.

Comment: Ok, sorry I got confused and i didn't understand quite well XD

Comment: I am searching for the same thing. Did you find anything?